# make list of CVS file w/o header

Tags: python, jython

this function finds the gives the population of either a specific state or all the states all the states when parameters is left blank. when I leave the parameters blanks though it gives me a error because there are headers in the first 3 rows of the file.

```
def findpop(state=None):
     f=open(getMediaPath("population_state_reduced (2).csv"),"rt")
     for line in f: 
       parts = line.split(',')
       if state is None:
          return [(parts[4], int(parts[5]))]
       else:
         for line in f:
             if parts[4] == state.capitalize():
                  return int(parts[5])
print findpop()
```

Comment: Skip over the first 3 lines: `for _ in range(3): next(f)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just skip the first 3 lines:

```
def findpop(state=None):
    f = open(getMediaPath("population_state_reduced (2).csv"), "rt")
    index = 1
    for line in f:
        if index > 3:
            parts = line.split(',')
            if state is None:
                return [(parts[4], int(parts[5]))]
            else:
                for line in f:
                    if parts[4] == state.capitalize():
                        return int(parts[5])
        index += 1

print findpop()
```

Comment: now it only returns line 3 instead of the whole column